# How can I filter on the type of query that I ran in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find a query that I closed one of my notebooks or in snowql, honestly I cannot remember. I am searching through the query history of the warehouse I used.

`SELECT *
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY()) where QUERY_TEXT like '%ArticleLibrary%'
ORDER BY start_time;`

There are alot of these though since I was running items every hour, it is possible to filter by ddl names in the Query_Text Column?

For example: 
...WHERE QUERY_TEXT like "%python code variable%" or "%Values(%b%%"...

where I am trying to search for a python variable I used or a specific time I inserted a specific value? (for which I entered a value that had badly formatted data. I am trying to determine how far back in the data I can start the import again to overwrite the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right approach. The python variable names will not normally appear in QUERY_HISTORY() though. Nor is there structured metadata about the tables and columns in the statement.  (Although within 24 hours you can get some of that from DESCRIBE RESULT or RESULTSCAN(), using the QUERY_ID from QUERY_HISTORY()).

Note you can proactively store metadata in the [QUERY_TAG](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag) session parameter or in comments within the query, and access them later in QUERY_HISTORY().  For example: SELECT /* my_var_name */ 1;  Then you can search QUERY_HISTORY() for '%my_var_name%'.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Yes, is it possible to set the query tag at the beginning of a session?

Comment: Yep.  You can set it anytime.  Queries thereafter will have that tag in the query_history().